# Unrecognized database format Error While Inserting Data With For Loop

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I want to insert data from `DatagridView1` to my Access (mdb) database on my Visual Basic Project. I have a large amount of data (approximately 12,000 lines) on `Datagridview1`. So I use a `For` loop to insert.

Here is my code:

```
   for i = 0 to Datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1
      a = Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
      b = Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
      c = Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
      d = Datagridview1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
      If studentsTableAdapter.CountStudent(a, b)=0 Then
         studentsTableAdapter.Insert(a, b, "-", "New", c, 1)
      End If
      infoTxt.Text = "Saving " & i & "/" & Total
      infoTxt.Refresh()
   Next i
```

It works as expected, but sometimes it stops to insert and an error occurs like:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Unrecognized database format

This error occurs on different steps of for loops. (some times it does not occur).

Is there any reliable way to insert large amount of data from `Datagridview1` to mdb database?

Comment: Is `studentsTableAdapter.Insert` something that you have written, and is that where the error occurs?

Comment: Error occurs at "studentsTableAdapter.Insert(a, b, "-", "New", c, 1)" but .Insert is the Visual Basic's own command that inserts data to database, thats not a query that i written